# Login does not work in django

Tags: python, django

I want to login with a username and password that is in the database. I get the error 'object has no attribute 'authenticate'.

*My code for views.py*

```
def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('polls/login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def auth(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('polls/create')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('polls/login')
```

*My login.html:*

```
    <form action="/polls/auth/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for = "username"> User name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
        <label for="password" > Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password" value="" id="password">

        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
```

Comment: did you import authenticate, login ?

Comment: from django.contrib import auth , yes

Comment: Please paste the full error with trace.

Answer (score 2):

Your are overriding the **auth** functionality by your view function **auth**.

For example if I import **sys** and create a same **function** name as **sys** then it overrides its functionality in the local namespace.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path[0]
''
>>> sys.path[1]
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
>>> def sys():
...     return "Hello"
... 
>>> sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'path'
```

So just change your **view** function name **auth** to some other name.

OR

Try to import your **auth** feature with different name.

```
from django.contrib import auth as django_auth

def auth(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = django_auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        django_auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('polls/create')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('polls/login')
```

Comment: or alternatively `from django.contrib import auth as django_auth` and then use `django_auth.authenticate` in the view

Comment: Yes that would be a solution but its better to avoid using imported name or pyhon keywords.

Comment: Thanks Tanveer Alam! But now will not redirect me to the next page. It will go on else path and redirect me on login page, over and over again. The user and password exist in DB.

Comment: Updated the answer. This is what Charl suggested.

Comment: @TanveerAlam I agree 100% about python keywords, often it can be nicer to alias an import and keep the most suitable name for your own function though

Answer (score 0):

Your function name is 'auth' and this clashes with the 'auth' module you are importing. Change your function name or you could use the 'as' import syntax:

```
from django.contrib import auth as django_auth
```

and then use it in your function:

```
user = django_auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```